# syscalls.h and minor() and major() functions

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, gnu

I am writing the class for handling matrices (no suprise here - the name is Matrix). I was suprised when it turned out that I cannot use minor() method name that counts the minor matrix. The name is #defined in sys/syscalls.h. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#undef` to remove the definition; be wary of changing behaviour in strange and unexpected ways.